# Converting Decimal to Hex (one byte Format)

Tags: c#, byte, hex

How can I convert a decimal number to hex with one byte format.

```
e.g if decimal = 15 , Output = 0x0F and Not 0xF ,
    if decimal = 240 , Output = 0xF0



Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", i) solutions gives 0xF not 0x0F.
```

IN the C# there is ToINt16/32/64 but no ToINt8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the number of characters to output

```
var value = String.Format("0x{0:X2}", 14);
```

This outputs `0x0E`.